# what is the longest number that pi can reach

Tags: pi

Where does π (pi) end? this is what I know: 3.14159265359.
This is from the Google search calculator. I know it never ends but I want to know how far we got π to.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635861/why-are-mathematicians-still-trying-to-calculate-digits-of-pi)

Comment: Additionally, I imagine the answer to this changes all the time.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for trying to help! I want to know what the number is. Thank you though.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn I'm not sure. Maybe it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last computation I heard of has found 50 trillion digits.It was done by Timothy Mullican on January 2020.
You can find more information about pi computations here
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80

Comment: I want to see the whole number or at least more than 50 digits.

Comment: https://www.piday.org/million/

Comment: @math.pr The link you gave looks broken...

Comment: Here is he link : https://blog.timothymullican.com/calculating-pi-my-attempt-breaking-pi-record

Comment: I have fixed it now

Comment: thanks all for answering and helping! I wanted to know how it is added.